# Solve the diophantine equation $(n+1)^{2}X+n^2Y=1$ where $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I having difficulty applying Euclid's algorithm to find a particular solution.

Comment: Is $n$ the variable here?

Comment: find answers for $n=1,2,3,4,5,6,7$  and write those on one page. A pattern emerges. I recommend taking the "smallest"  solution for each $n$ with $x<0$  and $y > 0$ With that in mind, if$(x,y)$   is a solution for $n$ and $t$  is any integer, another solution comes from any $(x-tn^2, y+t(n+1)^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either $n=2k$ or $n+1=2k$ for some integer $k$.

In the first case, Euclid's algorithm gives:$$\begin{array}{c|c} (2k+1)^2&4k^2\\4k+1&-k\\1 \end{array}$$

Working backwards: \begin{eqnarray*}1&=&(4k+1) +4(-k)\\
&=& (4k+1)+4(4k^2-k(4k+1)\\ &=& (1-4k)(4k+1)+4(4k^2)\\&=&
(1-4k)((2k+1)^2-(4k^2))+4(4k^2)\\&=&
(1-4k)(2k+1)^2 +(3+4k)(4k^2)\\&=&(1-4k)(n+1)^2+(3+4k)n^2
\end{eqnarray*}

Thus $X=1-2n, Y=3+2n$.

The second case follows exactly the same method, though it is not necessary to repeat it, as substituting the above values for $X,Y$ we find the equation holds for all $n$.

In both cases $n^2, (n+1)^2$ are coprime, so lcm$(n^2, (n+1)^2)=n^2(n+1)^2$.  Thus the solutions $$X=1-2n+tn^2,\qquad Y=3+2n-t(n+1)^2,\qquad t\in \mathbb{Z},$$
cover all cases.